# Как из svg изображения сделать такую анимацию?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animation

Есть svg изображение

```html
<svg width="449" height="720" viewBox="0 0 449 720" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M757 699.205L739.074 719.794M418.253 -175L117.831 -0.406012L418.253 -175ZM117.831 -0.611898L228.274 469.021L117.831 -0.611898ZM228.274 469.021L0.999973 720L228.274 469.021ZM256.503 521.317L155.95 92.8618L256.503 521.317ZM155.95 92.6559L186.033 57.4488L155.95 92.6559ZM469.765 76.5965L757 -89.556L469.765 76.5965ZM203.136 72.067L469.765 76.5965L203.136 72.067ZM95.3712 720L263.715 534.288L95.3712 720ZM263.715 534.288L165.634 116.127L263.715 534.288ZM165.428 116.127L202.93 72.067L165.428 116.127ZM540.235 92.0382L757 -33.1424L540.235 92.0382ZM220.238 86.6851L540.441 92.0382L220.238 86.6851ZM114.328 720L270.72 547.465L114.328 720ZM270.72 547.465L175.113 139.599L270.72 547.465ZM175.113 139.599L220.238 86.6851L175.113 139.599ZM611.116 107.686L757 23.2712L611.116 107.686ZM237.34 101.303L611.116 107.686L237.34 101.303ZM133.285 720L277.932 560.642L133.285 720ZM277.932 560.642L184.591 163.07L277.932 560.642ZM184.591 162.864L237.34 101.097L184.591 162.864ZM681.791 123.127L757 79.8907L681.791 123.127ZM254.442 115.921L681.791 123.127L254.442 115.921ZM152.447 720L285.144 573.819L152.447 720ZM285.144 573.819L194.276 186.541L285.144 573.819ZM194.276 186.335L254.442 115.921L194.276 186.335ZM752.879 138.775L757 136.304L752.879 138.775ZM271.751 130.539L752.879 138.775L271.751 130.539ZM171.404 720L292.15 586.996L171.404 720ZM292.15 586.996L203.754 210.013L292.15 586.996ZM203.754 210.013L271.545 130.539L203.754 210.013ZM288.853 145.158L757 153.187L288.853 145.158ZM190.567 720L299.361 600.173L190.567 720ZM299.361 600.173L213.438 233.484L299.361 600.173ZM213.438 233.484L288.853 145.158L213.438 233.484ZM306.161 159.982L757 167.6L306.161 159.982ZM209.729 720L306.573 613.349L209.729 720ZM306.573 613.349L222.917 256.955L306.573 613.349ZM222.917 256.955L305.955 159.776L222.917 256.955ZM323.263 174.6L757 182.012L323.263 174.6ZM228.892 720L313.785 626.732L228.892 720ZM313.579 626.732L232.395 280.633L313.579 626.732ZM232.601 280.633L323.263 174.6L232.601 280.633ZM340.572 189.424L756.794 196.424L340.572 189.424ZM248.055 720L320.791 639.909L248.055 720ZM320.791 639.909L242.079 304.104L320.791 639.909ZM242.285 304.104L340.778 189.218L242.285 304.104ZM357.88 204.042L757 210.836L357.88 204.042ZM267.217 720L328.002 653.292L267.217 720ZM328.002 653.086L251.764 327.781L328.002 653.086ZM251.764 327.781L357.88 204.042L251.764 327.781ZM375.188 218.866L757 225.248L375.188 218.866ZM286.586 720L335.214 666.469L286.586 720ZM335.214 666.469L261.448 351.458L335.214 666.469ZM261.448 351.458L375.188 218.866L261.448 351.458ZM392.496 233.69L756.794 239.867L392.496 233.69ZM305.955 720L342.426 679.852L305.955 720ZM342.426 679.852L271.132 375.136L342.426 679.852ZM271.132 375.136L392.496 233.69L271.132 375.136ZM410.011 248.514L757 254.279L410.011 248.514ZM325.324 720L349.844 693.234L325.324 720ZM349.638 693.029L280.817 398.813L349.638 693.029ZM280.817 398.813L410.011 248.514L280.817 398.813ZM427.319 263.338L757 268.897L427.319 263.338ZM344.693 720L357.056 706.411L344.693 720ZM356.85 706.411L290.501 422.49L356.85 706.411ZM290.501 422.696L427.319 263.338L290.501 422.696ZM444.833 278.162L757 283.515L444.833 278.162ZM364.267 719.794L300.392 446.373L364.267 719.794ZM300.186 446.373L444.833 278.162L300.186 446.373ZM462.141 292.986L757 298.133L462.141 292.986ZM368.388 720L310.076 470.257L368.388 720ZM309.87 470.257L462.141 293.192L309.87 470.257ZM479.656 308.016L757 312.751L479.656 308.016ZM372.509 720L319.76 493.934L372.509 720ZM319.554 493.934L479.656 307.81L319.554 493.934ZM497.17 322.84L757 327.369L497.17 322.84ZM376.63 720L329.445 517.817L376.63 720ZM329.445 517.817L497.17 322.84L329.445 517.817ZM514.684 337.87L757 341.988L514.684 337.87ZM380.751 720L339.129 541.7L380.751 720ZM339.129 541.7L514.684 337.87L339.129 541.7ZM532.199 352.694L757 356.606L532.199 352.694ZM384.872 720L348.814 565.583L384.872 720ZM348.814 565.583L532.199 352.694L348.814 565.583ZM549.713 367.724L757 371.224L549.713 367.724ZM388.993 720L358.498 589.672L388.993 720ZM358.498 589.466L549.713 367.724L358.498 589.466ZM567.433 382.754L757 386.048L567.433 382.754ZM393.321 720L368.388 613.555L393.321 720ZM368.388 613.555L567.433 382.754L368.388 613.555ZM584.948 397.784L756.794 400.666L584.948 397.784ZM397.442 720L378.279 637.438L397.442 720ZM378.073 637.438L584.948 397.784L378.073 637.438ZM602.668 412.813L757 415.49L602.668 412.813ZM401.563 720L387.963 661.528L401.563 720ZM387.963 661.528L602.668 412.813L387.963 661.528ZM620.388 427.843L757 430.108L620.388 427.843ZM405.684 720L397.648 685.617L405.684 720ZM397.648 685.617L620.388 427.843L397.648 685.617ZM637.903 443.079L756.794 445.138L637.903 443.079ZM410.011 720L407.538 709.706L410.011 720ZM407.538 709.5L637.903 443.079L407.538 709.5ZM655.623 458.109L756.794 459.756L655.623 458.109ZM429.173 720L655.623 458.109L429.173 720ZM673.549 473.139L757 474.58L673.549 473.139ZM459.875 720L673.549 473.139L459.875 720ZM515.303 -175L188.094 14.8298L515.303 -175ZM757 -145.97L399.09 61.1548L757 -145.97ZM612.352 -175L258.357 30.2715L612.352 -175ZM709.608 -175L328.621 45.7132L709.608 -175ZM188.094 14.8298L134.933 14.0062L188.094 14.8298ZM399.09 61.1548L186.033 57.4488L399.09 61.1548ZM258.357 30.2715L152.035 28.4185L258.357 30.2715ZM328.621 45.7132L168.931 43.0366L328.621 45.7132ZM757 489.404L691.27 488.375L757 489.404ZM757 504.434L708.99 503.611L757 504.434ZM757 519.258L726.917 518.846L757 519.258ZM757 534.082L744.637 533.876L757 534.082ZM235.28 481.992L19.7506 720L235.28 481.992ZM256.503 521.317L76.4145 720L256.503 521.317ZM242.491 495.169L38.7072 720L242.491 495.169ZM249.497 508.14L57.4579 720L249.497 508.14ZM127.309 22.6536L235.28 481.992L127.309 22.6536ZM136.993 45.919L242.491 494.963L136.993 45.919ZM146.472 69.3904L249.497 508.14L146.472 69.3904ZM134.933 13.8003L127.515 22.6536L134.933 13.8003ZM151.829 28.4185L136.787 45.919L151.829 28.4185ZM168.931 42.8307L146.472 69.1845L168.931 42.8307ZM691.27 488.375L490.782 720L691.27 488.375ZM708.99 503.611L521.484 720L708.99 503.611ZM726.917 518.846L552.598 720L726.917 518.846ZM744.637 533.876L583.299 719.794L744.637 533.876ZM757 555.701L614.413 720L757 555.701ZM757 591.525L645.527 720L757 591.525ZM757 627.35L676.64 720L757 627.35ZM757 663.38L707.754 720L757 663.38Z" stroke="#333333" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
```

Как из этого  сделать такую анимацию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала чуть чуть теории:

Любой путь(path) начинается с команды M или m и кончается Z или z

Что бы отрисовать такую анимацию на smil в ручную придётся потратить колосальные силы и усидчивость и по этому что я сделал

1. В самом начале на регулярках разбил на новую строку всё что начинается от M и до z и обернул в такую конструкцию `<path d=" здесь то что с новой строки" />` и сохранил в файл line.svg
2. Подключил библиотеку http://lazylinepainter.info/ и получил эту анимацию

> Так как длина ответа на stackoverflow не позволяет дать сообщение
> длиной больше 30000 симолов я эту анимацию поместил на
> https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/LYGZqgX

```
(function() {

    document.onreadystatechange = () => {

      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {

        /**
         * Setup your Lazy Line element.
         * see README file for more settings
         */

        let el = document.querySelector('#line');
        let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {
          "ease": "easeLinear",
          "strokeWidth": 1,
          "strokeOpacity": 1,
          "strokeColor": "#222F3D",
          "strokeCap": "square"
        });
        myAnimation.paint();
      }
    }

  })();
```

Comment: Чисто интересно, а не проще ли данную анимацию написать на canvas?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 исходник же в SVG

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо за ответ. Очень круто!
Из ответа меня заинтересовал еще один момент.
Как средствами js разбить svg регулярками и сохранить в отдельный файл?

Comment: @MaximLensky, не, я про вообще

Comment: @ref21, это уже другая тема, лучше задать [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: @ref21 я в редакторе кода делал - там есть регулярки - на ютубе этому учился

Comment: Спасибо, полезная штука)
Начинаю гуглить))

Comment: @ref21 можете задать новый  вопрос в котором спросите - как сделать подобное js но с сохранением в файл будет проблема - так как js работает в браузере - могу ошибаться - здесь есть гиганты js или гуру - которые если не поленятся расскажут как это сделать

Comment: @MaximLensky обязательно задам такой вопрос. Думаю, с сохранением в файл поможет node.js